# Is any Javascript charting which draw like clockwise with multiple points

Tags: javascript, charts

I am looking for a JavaScript live chart/graph library that looks like this and draws clockwise with multiple points. Is there one available?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can try jgauge. I used it one of my projects. For reference: https://code.google.com/p/jgauge/